# Bind Nested object to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to Bind ChildProperty to the TextBox in xaml.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="ChildProperty" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=ChildProperty}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="50"/>
        <TextBlock Text="ParentProperty" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ParentProperty}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="50"/>
    </Grid>
```

DataContext:

```
public NotifyParentChangePropertyInChildClass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ParentClass();
        }
```

Parent & Child Class:

```
public class ParentClass :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int parentProperty;
        public int ParentProperty
        {
            get { return parentProperty; }
            set 
            { 
                parentProperty = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ParentProperty");
            }
        }
        public ParentClass()
        {
            ChildClass obj = new ChildClass();
            obj.ChildProperty = 100;
            parentProperty = 200;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class ChildClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int childProperty;
        public int ChildProperty
        {
            get { return childProperty; }
            set 
            { 
                childProperty = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ChildProperty");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run above code, In out put window Message `"System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ChildProperty' property not found on 'object' ''ParentClass' (HashCode=59593954)'. BindingExpression:Path=ChildProperty; DataItem='ParentClass' (HashCode=59593954); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')"`

Answer (score 0):

The Error you are getting is right.  You had set the DataContext to be ParentClass, whereas you are setting the binding property from ChildClass.  You can only have one DataContext.  To use both the properties you can define the properties in same class or derive from one and use the child class as datacontext.

Comment: I want to have these properties in the separate classes. I cannot define both properties in the same class.

Comment: Only way to bind if the property is of different class is, jumping in visual tree using RelativeSource or Element Name.

Comment: Why not derive the class in ChildClass and set as DataContext?

Comment: I set DataContext as Parent Class with this How we can use Relative source to get the property from child class for Textbox

Answer (score 0):

Define property of Type `ChildClass` in ParentClass as below:

```
    ChildClass _childClass;
    public ChildClass ChildClass
    {
        get { return _childClass; }
        set { _childClass = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ChildClass"); }
    }
```

and in constructor of ParentClass initialize instance of _childClass.

Change the binding of textbox as:

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=**ChildClass.ChildProperty**}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="50"/>
```

Thanks